# How to make text not move around after adding border

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a navigation bar that upon hovering, adds a border to it. The problem is every time the border is added/removed, the text will shift slightly. Is there anyway I can solve this?

```js
function toHomePage(){
    window.location.replace("...");
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navBar").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css("border","2px solid black");
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).css("border","none");
    });
})
```

```css
.navBar{
    display: flex;
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    padding: 20px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    z-index: 2;
    
 }
 #Title{
     color: black;
     font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Help.css">
    <title>Help</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navBar" onclick="toHomePage()">
        <div>
            <h1 id="Title">SomeRandomWebsite</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="Help.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a border, just change the color of the border.

```js
function toHomePage(){
    window.location.replace("...");
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navBar").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css("borderColor","black");
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).css("borderColor","gainsboro");
    });
})
```

```css
.navBar {
    display: flex;
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    padding: 20px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    z-index: 2;
    border: 2px solid gainsboro;
}
 #Title {
     color: black;
     font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Help.css">
    <title>Help</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navBar" onclick="toHomePage()">
        <div>
            <h1 id="Title">SomeRandomWebsite</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="Help.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: You can also use the [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) property which will not make a change to the box model.

I'm sure you have your reasons for using js for this but the [CSS `:hover` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) is a better way for doing this.
Also using an HTML anchor is a better device to link to things. I just leave this here for prosperity.

```css
.navBar {
    display: flex;
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    padding: 20px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    z-index: 2;
    border: 2px solid gainsboro;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navBar:hover {
    border-color: black;
}
 #Title {
     color: black;
     font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Help.css">
    <title>Help</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#0" class="navBar">
        <div>
            <h1 id="Title">SomeRandomWebsite</h1>
        </div>
    </a>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="Help.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dominik's answer, you can also use a `box-shadow`.

```js
function toHomePage(){
    window.location.replace("...");
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navBar").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css("box-shadow","0px 0px 0px 1px black");
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).css("box-shadow","none");
    });
})
```

```css
.navBar{
    display: flex;
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    padding: 20px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    z-index: 2;
    
 }
 #Title{
     color: black;
     font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Help.css">
    <title>Help</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navBar" onclick="toHomePage()">
        <div>
            <h1 id="Title">SomeRandomWebsite</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="Help.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle only from the css as example below:

```
p.solid {border:1px solid transparent;}
p.solid:hover {border:1px solid #0f0;}

<p class="solid">A solid border.</p>
```

In your example you can use border with full border-width but we need to add transparent color:

```js
function toHomePage(){
    window.location.replace("...");
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navBar").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css("border","2px solid black");
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).css("border","2px solid transparent");
    });
})
```

```css
.navBar {
    display: flex;
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    z-index: 2;
    border: 2px solid gainsboro;
}
 #Title {
     color: black;
     font-family: monospace;
}
```